# Catch the error on if statement powershell

Tags: powershell

Im trying to catch the error set default value. Im confused how to do it. If the smtp is incorrect i would like to set the default value in smtp relay. Sorry im really new powershell and scripting.

```
    if ($To -eq "")
    {
    write-host "use the default value test2@test.com"
    $To = "test2@test.com"
    }
    if ($From -eq "")
    {
    write-host "use the default value MailboxReport"
    $From = "MailboxReport@test.com"
    }
    if ($Subject -eq "")
    {
    write-host "use the default value MailboxReport"
    $Subject = "MailboxReport"
    }
    if ($body -eq "")
    {
    write-host "use the default value mail"
    $body = "mail" 
    }
    if ($SmtpServer -eq "") 
    {
       write-host "use the default value XX.XXX.XXX.XX"
       $SmtpServer = "XX.XXX.XXX.XX"
    }

Send-MailMessage -to $To -From $From -Subject $Subject -Body $body -SmtpServer $SmtpServer -Attachments $Filereport
write-host "******************MailSent******************"
```

---

Error

> Send-MailMessage : The remote name could not be resolved: '1235656+'
>   At C:\Scripts\Exchange\Mailbox.ps1:309 char:21
>   +     Send-MailMessage <<<<  -to $To -From $From -Subject $Subject -Body $body -SmtpServer $SmtpServer -Attachments $Filereport
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient:SmtpClient) [Send-MailMessage],
>   SmtpException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SmtpException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SendMailMessage

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this:

```
try{
    Send-MailMessage -to $To -From $From -Subject $Subject -Body $body -SmtpServer $SmtpServer -Attachments $Filereport -ErrorAction Stop
}
catch{
    $SmtpServer = "XX.XXX.XXX.XX" #default server
    Send-MailMessage -to $To -From $From -Subject $Subject -Body $body -SmtpServer $SmtpServer -Attachments $Filereport
}
```

Comment: You need to force `-ErrorAction Stop` common parameter (apply to `Send-MailMessage`) to handle non-terminating errors as well using `Try` - `Catch` - `Finally` blocks.

Comment: Good call...fixed

Comment: thank for the responsed. I did this. Send-MailMessage -to $To -From $From -Subject $Subject -Body $body -SmtpServer $SmtpServer -Attachments $Filereport -EV error 
if($error){$SmtpServer = "XX.XXX.XXX.XX" Send-MailMessage -to $To -From $From -Subject $Subject -Body $body -SmtpServer $SmtpServer -Attachments $Filereport }

Comment: Don't use $error. That is a collection of all the errors that have happened in the session. I sometimes do what you are trying to do by using if(!$?){} that will basically say "If the last operation did not return a success then do this"